# Core Data multiple relationships to similar objects, can't inverse

Tags: core-data, entity, inverse

I have an Entity `Storm`, which has two One-to-Many relationships, "history" and "forecast" both of these are NSSets that contain a `StormPosition` Entity which contains time, latitude and longitude.

I am able to build this but while I can set up the "history" and "forecast" relationship, they can't seem to both point to objects of type `StormPosition` because the inverse relationships can't both point back to the Storm Entity.

I assume this is because when I do:

```
myStormPosition.owner = self
```

it needs to know which NSSet (history or forecast) to place it into.

Do I need to mix these into one "track" relationship? I'd rather not since it is nice to have one set for history and one set for forecast without having to examine the date property.

Also, elsewhere in the program I'd like to be able to only work with a `StormPosition` type instead of a `HistoricPosition` and `PredictedPosition` type which would effectively be the same but make for difficult type casting unless I gave them both a parent class that was identical.

Comment: One solution is to have one entity and add a bool attribute isForecast. You could then create two “default” fetch requests for history and forecast so it becomes easy to select one type. Although I must admit I don’t understand why you can’t have two entities that both have a relationship to a third entity, it sounds like a common setup to me. Regarding working with only one type in your code, here you could create a protocol that both the history and forecast entity conforms to.

Answer (score 0):

This does feel to me like one of the rare occasions when you would benefit from using a parent entity/class. Be careful with this, because all instances of both `HistoricPosition` and `PredictedPosition` will have eat space in the persistent store for all of properties of both (because they have a common parent).

Will you have multiple Forecasts per storm? E.g. predicted track as of day 1, predicted track as of day 2, …?

It does feel like a heavyweight solution, though. Perhaps a protocol to include the location and timestamp? Get away fromthe notion of a Position entity completely? A forecast position has a valid time, and the time it was issued, while a historic track position has only the time it was recorded.